# ASP.NET model binding breaks when using decimal values

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model-binding

I have the following scenario. I have a form that post to a controller. Everything works fine when I enter a non decimal number on `ValorKilometro` input. I can get the model perfectly on the controller and so. The thing is that when I enter a decimal value the `ValorKilometro` property is always set to 0. Why is that?. Here is the code:

```
<form name="theForm" action="" style="margin: 0 auto; width: 80%;" method="post" onsubmit="return onFormSubmit();">
    ...
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="usr">Valor de Kilometro:</label>
        <input type="number" name="ValorKilometro" min="0" step="any" class="form-control" value="@Model.ValorKilometro">
    </div>
    <button type="submit" id="boton" class="btn btn-success">Guardar</button>
</form>
```

Model:

```
public class ConfiguracionModel
{
    public Guid EmpresaGuid { get; set; }
    public bool MaximoHabilitado { get; set; }
    public int MontoMaximo { get; set; }
    public Guid Moneda { get; set; }
    public Double ValorKilometro { get; set; }
}
```

Controller:

```
    [Authorize, AdminAuthorization]
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Configuracion(ConfiguracionModel configuracion)
    {
        configuracion.EmpresaGuid = SQL.GetEmpresaGuid(User.Identity.Name);

        SQL.ModificarConfiguracion(configuracion);

        TempData["msg"] = "<script>alert('Los cambios fueron guardados correctamente!.');</script>";

        return View(configuracion);
    }
```

I hope someone can help me out with this.Thanks.

Comment: What is your server culture? What are you entering for the decimal separator?

Comment: And what does `onFormSubmit()` do?  What does the controller action look like?

Comment: @StephenMuecke the server culture is 'es-ES'.

Comment: @BrendanGreen actually onFormSubmit() does nothing. I got to remove it.

Comment: The controller does nothing special but I added it anyway so you can see it.

Comment: Doesn't `es-ES` use a decimal comma?  What is an example of the data being input on the form?

Comment: @BrendanGreen Yes it does. The strange thing is that even if I use ',' or '.' the output is the same: 0. If I enter a round value gets perfect to the controller.

Comment: Is the culture your browser uses the same as the server? What happens if you use a text input rather than a number?

Comment: Have you verified, via the Browser Dev Tools, what payload is sent to the server when the form is submitted?  I'd be curious to see what it looks like,

Comment: @BrendanGreen the value is correctly sent on the payload. I think this is strictly a binding issue

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using `@Html.TextBoxFor` helper?

```
@model ConfiguracionModel // <-- obviously you need to bind your View to your model

@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.ValorKilometro, "{0:n2}", new { 
    @class = "form-control", 
    @type = "number", 
    @min = "0" })
```

You can also add the validation constraint to your model:

```
public class ConfiguracionModel
{
   public Guid EmpresaGuid { get; set; }
   public bool MaximoHabilitado { get; set; }
   public int MontoMaximo { get; set; }
   public Guid Moneda { get; set; }

   [Range(0.0, double.MaxValue)]
   [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:n2}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
   public Double ValorKilometro { get; set; }
}
```

Note that `{0:n2}` indicates 2 decimal places.